# I want to save everything in a UITableView controller, with a button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to save everything in a UITableView controller, with a button, I dont know how to do that.   I know it has a saving method, but when you press back to the homescreen of the app, and go back to the viewcontroller, the text is gone, or when i deleted something its still there.

code in my .m file

```
#import "HomeWorkViewController.h"

@interface HomeWorkViewController ()

@end

@implementation HomeWorkViewController
@synthesize adView;
@synthesize myTableView, numbers;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
   adView.delegate=self;
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    // check here if key exists in the defaults or not, if yes the retrieve results in array
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberArray"] != nil) {
       self.numbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"numberArray"]];
    }

    //Register for the notification when user go to background or minimize the app, just save the array objects in the defaults
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(appWillGoToBackground:)
                                            name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];

    //Add the Add button
    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                   target: self action: @selector(insertNewObject)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.myTableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

-(void)appWillGoToBackground:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"terminate");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:self.numbers forKey:@"numberArray"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(void)insertNewObject{
    //Display a UIAlertView
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter HomeWork" message: @"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Only perform the following actions if the user hits the ok button
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        NSString * tmpTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        if(!self. numbers){
            self.numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        [self.numbers insertObject:tmpTextField atIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.numbers.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                        reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
   {
      //remove our NSMutableArray
      [self.numbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      //remove from our tableView
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    adView.hidden=FALSE;
    NSLog(@"Has ad, showing");
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    adView.hidden=TRUE;
    NSLog(@"Has no ads, hiding");
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [adView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end
```

Comment: The question is not clear, need more clarification. However I understood u can do it passing a delegate for HomeViewController to TableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are only saving your data when the application enters the background. If you want to persist the data immediately instead of just when the app closes, just write your array to NSUserDefaults in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:

Comment: You would also want to move the code where you assign the saved array from NSUserDefaults to self.numbers to viewWillAppear